# Proper Architecture and role for SP server

Tags: active-directory, architecture

we are (small office with 30 user) testing SharePoint for improving in document and workflow management.
we have five server (appserver, fileserver, DC and 2 kerio server) running on Esxi so i add new VM and install windows server 2012 and SQL 2014 on it.   if we can add an other physical server Which Architecture is proper for test duration and future?
1)Server 1(+new VM for SharePoint), Server 2 (SQL)
2)Server 1(+new VM for SQL), Server 2 (SP)
3)Server 2 ESXI with 2 VM(SQL and SP)
4)server 2 win server with SP and SQL

Q2: these [tutorial](http://blog.anuragg.com/2012/12/install-and-configure-sharepoint-server_25.html) and [course](http://www.lynda.com/Office-tutorials/SharePoint-Server-2013-Essential-Training/121679-2.html) for AD, setup new forest but as we have a domain controller in our network should i choose "add new domain controller for existing domain"? if it is true which other capabilities would be needed (DNS, Global catalog, Read only DC, install from media or replicate existing DC)?

i think my problem is very basic so any help, resource or course recommendation would be great.

Comment: I understand you alreay have a Domain... why do you create a new forest? SharePoint installs in your existing domain (and does not change anything in it).

Comment: @Evariste i didn't create a new forest (post edited), sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal architecture I usually recommend is 2 servers: one for SQL and one for SP (hosting all SP roles). For 30 users, a single "all-in-one" server would be enough in terms of performances (by far), but a two-servers architecture is much more clean if you can afford it.

Comment: thanks, any help with 2nd part of question ?

Comment: You don't need to setup a new DC for your SP install. The SP servers (both SP and SQL) will be member of your current domain, hosted by your current DC. No problem with that.

Comment: can you explain more "You don't need to setup a new DC". you mean no need to add AD role? or no need to promote server ? or sth elc?

Comment: If you already have a domain/DC (that's what I though while reading your question: "as we have a domain controller in our network"), you don't need to add anything to setup SharePoint: SharePoint will be part of that existing domain. However, if you have currently no domain at all, yes, you have to setup your first DC/domain/forest (default options should be good; a DNS will be required, but the AD wizard will guide you on this).